# .classList applicated to a null objectif without reasons

Tags: javascript

thanks for the help. For a homework i just have to create a form like the on i join. 
I have to remove class of an object in a function, but it returns an error that tells it's a null object. As you'll be able to se, it is good in the HTML :/

THanks !

```
function checked(x) {
for (i=1; i <= x; i++) {
    let non = "#non"+i;
    let oui = "#oui"+i;
    document.getElementById("oui"+i).addEventListener('click', function() {
        this.className = 'cheked';
        if (document.getElementById("non"+i).classList.contains("cheked") ==  true) {
            $(this).classList.remove("cheked");
        }
    });
    document.getElementById("non"+i).addEventListener('click', function() {
        this.className = 'cheked';
        if (document.getElementById("oui"+i).classList.contains("cheked") ==  true) {
            $(this).classList.remove("cheked");
        }
    });
}
```

}

```
<form id="question1">
    <h2>Salamèche est-il de type feu ?</h2>
    <div class="row">
        <div>
            <input type="radio" name="question1" id="oui1" value="oui" >
            <label for="oui1" class="oui">OUI</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="radio" name="question1" id="non1" value="non">
            <label for="non1" class="non ">NON</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<form id="question2">
    <h2>Tiplouf est-il de type plante ?</h2>
    <div class="row">
        <div>
            <input type="radio" name="question1" id="oui2" value="oui" >
            <label for="oui2" class="oui">OUI</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="radio" name="question1" id="non2" value="non">
            <label for="non2" class="non ">NON</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<form id="question3">
    <h2>Wesh la cité</h2>
    <div class="row">
        <div>
            <input type="radio" name="question1" id="oui3" value="oui" >
            <label for="oui3" class="oui">OUI</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="radio" name="question1" id="non3" value="non">
            <label for="non3" class="non ">NON</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Are you still having issues?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you could go about this:

```js
// select all radio buttons and save them in an array
var radioButtons = [].slice.call(
  document.querySelectorAll("input[type='radio']")
);

// create an event handler for each `radio` button
// and listen for the `change` event, which will
// get triggered when you select one
radioButtons.forEach(function (button) {
  button.addEventListener("change", handleOnChange);
})

function handleOnChange(event) {
  // iterate through each `radio` button to check
  // which ones are `selected` and which ones are not
  radioButtons.forEach(function(button) {
    var CHECKED_CLASS = "checked";

    var buttonId = button.getAttribute("id");
    
    // grab `label` element corresponding to this `radio` button
    var label = document.querySelector("label[for='" + buttonId +"']");

    // if `button` is checked, add the `CHECKED_CLASS` to the `label`
    // element, otherwise remove it, or, alternatively, add/remove
    // class from the element itself
    if (button.checked) {
      label.classList.add(CHECKED_CLASS);
      // button.classList.add(CHECKED_CLASS);
    } else {
      label.classList.remove(CHECKED_CLASS);
      // button.classList.remove(CHECKED_CLASS);
    }
  })
}
```

```css
.checked {
  border: 3px solid green;
}
```

```html
<form id="question1">
  <h2>Salamèche est-il de type feu ?</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div>
      <input type="radio" name="question1" id="oui1" value="oui" />
      <label for="oui1" class="oui">
        OUI
      </label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" name="question1" id="non1" value="non" />
      <label for="non1" class="non ">
        NON
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<form id="question2">
  <h2>Tiplouf est-il de type plante ?</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div>
      <input type="radio" name="question1" id="oui2" value="oui" />
      <label for="oui2" class="oui">
        OUI
      </label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" name="question1" id="non2" value="non" />
      <label for="non2" class="non ">
        NON
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<form id="question3">
  <h2>Wesh la cité</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div>
      <input type="radio" name="question1" id="oui3" value="oui" />
      <label for="oui3" class="oui">
        OUI
      </label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" name="question1" id="non3" value="non" />
      <label for="non3" class="non ">
        NON
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```